# How do I keep the contents in my array?

Tags: java

This class is used for storing and processing the board in the game.

```java
static class Board
    {
    boolean[][] array;

    private void reset()
    {
        array = new boolean[][]
            {
                {false, false, false},
                {false, false, false},
                {false, false, false}
            };
    }

    private void mark(int row, int col)
    {
        array[row][col] = true;
    }
}
```

Here is the main method.

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    new Board().reset();
    new Board().mark(0,0);
}
```

I initialize the board with the reset method when the program starts.
Then, I use "mark" to change one of the booleans from false to true.

I get a null exception error at `array[row][col] = true;` because the array is null.

How can I edit the code so that array does not become null and mark() can properly write a value into the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't create two instances of `Board`. Create one instance and call both methods on the same isntance.

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Board board =  new Board();
    board.reset();
    board.mark(0,0);
}
```

When you create a new `Board` instance for each method call, the `mark` method is executed for an instance whose `array` member is not initialzied, causing the `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you're calling `mark` in a new instance of `Board` that has `array` initialized with `null` value. You have to reuse the same instance to call both methods:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Board board = new Board();
    board.reset();
    board.mark(0,0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't create a new object by calling the constructor `new Board()`
each time. Create just one object and then reuse it. Seems that was
your intention here.

```
Board obj = new Board();
obj.reset();
obj.mark(0,0);
```